# youtube Iframe playlist can't hide title of each videos

Tags: youtube, controls, playlist

I am playing a Youtube playlist of 3 short videos on my website.
My problem is I can't hide the title of each video when the playlist passes from one video to another.
It always shows titles and Youtube logo for a couple of seconds.
I used parameters like controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1 but it didn't help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i recall correctly, this cannot be done with url parameters, hence, you have to mess around with CSS.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I try to add Css in Divi Custom CSS, it doesn't work...

Comment: Please search here or Stack Overflow or in internet in general about you can override youtube css styles, I can't recall at this moment, but, I do read about a solution using css - read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201874/12511801) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Byoutube%5D+css). Best of luck.